# How to hide file extensions in PowerShell tab completion?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

How do I change the default Powershell CLI behavior to ignore file extensions for filetypes that live on my `$Env:Path` environment variable?

If I just type `python`, it works correctly and drops me into the Python interpreter as I expect since the extension is part of the environment variable.

The problem is that when I type `pyth` and tab-complete in PowerShell, it always appends the `.exe`. I just want it to finish the first part of the command without the extension.

Is this possible? Maybe a script?

Comment: If you don’t like file extensions, don’t use Windows. `cmd` also completes including file extensions. That’s just how things work.

Comment: That's not exactly the answer I was looking for... Is there maybe a way to script the behavior with a Powershell profile or something else?

Comment: Highly unlikely. However, you can take a look at what [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) does and maybe derive a solution. It involves (.NET) programming, of course.

Comment: What is the problem when you see the complete file name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the standard tab completion function with your own. In the newest version of PowerShell, that function is `TabExpansion2`. This modification of it appears to do what you want:

```
Function TabExpansion2 {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string] $inputScript,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [int] $cursorColumn,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast] $ast,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Language.Token[]] $tokens,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Language.IScriptPosition] $positionOfCursor,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptInputSet', Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AstInputSet', Position = 3)]
        [Hashtable] $options = $null
    )

    End
    {
        $source = $null
        if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ScriptInputSet')
        {
            $source = [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
                <#inputScript#>  $inputScript,
                <#cursorColumn#> $cursorColumn,
                <#options#>      $options)
        }
        else
        {
            $source = [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
                <#ast#>              $ast,
                <#tokens#>           $tokens,
                <#positionOfCursor#> $positionOfCursor,
                <#options#>          $options)
        }
        $field = [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult].GetField('completionText', 'Instance, NonPublic')
        $source.CompletionMatches | % {
            If ($_.ResultType -eq 'Command' -and [io.file]::Exists($_.ToolTip)) {
                $field.SetValue($_, [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.CompletionText))
            }
        }
        Return $source
    }    
}
```

I added the lines after the one that starts with `$field`; it goes through the default tab completion options and lops the extension off ones that appear to be from your `PATH`. I got the original source with this command:

```
(Get-Command 'TabExpansion2').ScriptBlock
```

If you put the new function in a `.ps1` file and dot-execute that script (e.g. `. .\tabnoext.ps1`), it will become the tab completion handler for the current session. To load it every time you open a PowerShell window, just paste all that code into a [PowerShell profile script](https://superuser.com/a/1090171/380318).

If you're on an old version of PowerShell, you need to override the [`TabExpansion`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/26/the-new-tabexpansion-feature/) function, which just returns an array of strings.

Comment: This works great, thank you.  Is there a way to source files in the powershell profile so that I can separate the function into its own file?

Comment: I just tried adding the dot source to the override script in my profile and it worked, so it looks like the answer is yes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Worth noting, I've not been able to get this to work without defining the function as `global` i.e `Function global:TabExpansion2 {`